# TKinter Entry validation not working after setting its StringVar

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a TKinter entry widget where i want to validate the input, and everything works as expected.

But when I set the StringVariable of the Entry widget the validation function is no more called.
Can someone explain me this behavior?

Here is an example of my problem where i validate whether the input is a digit or not

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.var1 = tk.StringVar()

        valid_cmd = (self.register(self.on_validate), '%S')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.var1, validate="key", validatecommand=valid_cmd)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")

        self.var1.set("25")         # comment out this line and validation function works as expected

    def on_validate(self, S):
        print("in validation function")
        if S.isdigit():
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Tk.geometry(root, '200x40')
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to change the value of the StringVar (and therefore the content of the Entry Widget) without loosing the validation function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [canonical documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7) says about using variables and entry validation together:

> In general, the **textVariable** and **validateCommand** can be dangerous to mix. Any problems have been overcome so that using the **validateCommand** will not interfere with the traditional behavior of the entry widget. Using the **textVariable** for read-only purposes will never cause problems. The danger comes when you try set the **textVariable** to something that the **validateCommand** would not accept, which causes **validate** to become none (the **invalidCommand** will not be triggered). The same happens when an error occurs evaluating the **validateCommand**.

> Primarily, an error will occur when the **validateCommand** or **invalidCommand** encounters an error in its script while evaluating or **validateCommand** does not return a valid Tcl boolean value. The **validate** option will also set itself to **none** when you edit the entry widget from within either the **validateCommand** or the **invalidCommand**. Such editions will override the one that was being validated. If you wish to edit the entry widget (for example set it to {}) during validation and still have the validate option set, you should include the command

In your case, when you call `self.var1.set("25")`, that triggers the validation function. When that happens, the validation function is sent an empty string. This is due to the fact that `%S` represents data to be *inserted* and you aren't inserting text, you are *setting* the text. That causes your function to return `False`, and thus validation is turned off.

The solution is to not use the `textvariable` option. Instead, directly insert text into the widget with `insert`, which will pass the value "25" to your validation function.

```
self.entry.insert(0, "25")
```

Comment: Thank you very much that solved my problem. I have been setting StringVars in my code all over the place. Now changed it to inserting all values directly to the widgets and it works like a charm